# My device doesn't receive other notification (FCM)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I migrated to Firebase Cloud Messaging and when first tried sending message I received a notification using the console in Firebase and then attempted to send another notification after a few minutes but i no longer receives another notification but in my firebase console it said that it was `Completed`

**update**

Here is my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 checkPlayServices();

 Log.i(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

}
....
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService  extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";


// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
// [END receive_message]
```

it seems that other devices receives it but the other devices doesn't received it.

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I added my code.

Comment: Was your app in the foreground when sending the second notification? Did you see if onMessageReceived() was called via the log statements?

Comment: @AdamK yes my app was in foreground when sending the second notifcation and `onMessageReceived()` was not called.

Comment: @AdamK thanks! I solve it now :)

Comment: @mori excellent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to AdamK's comment asking if I send the second notification while in foreground, I found out that notification is only triggered when my app is in the background.

In the documentation it was said that in `onMessageReceived()`, *If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages in the `onMessageReceived()`.* Therefore a notification will not be triggered automatically if the app is in foreground, so in order to do that, in your `onMessageReceived()` callback you need to trigger a notification yourself.

I call my own `sendNotification()` method inside my `onMessageReceived()`:

`sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());`

Which shows the notification even when the app is in the foreground.

Comment: Properly tag this as answer. :)

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Do you mind elaborating? Do you know get it to see Notification in both foreground and background? My point of confusion is that if `onMessageReceived` is not called anyway, why does it matter that you call `sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())` from inside `onMessageReceived`? Or are you making that call from somewhere else?