# I can't receive notifications to my device using FCM

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

First and foremost I read a similar question about this issue, but It didn't solve my issue. This is the question [FCM question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383684/my-device-doesnt-receive-other-notification-fcm)

I have implemented almost each and everything, but I don't know if I have left something out. I tested the notifications on the API 27 and 28 version devices but it didn't work out. Even the logs aren't displaying in the `onMessageReceived()`, I checked the `google-service.json` file and seems okay, so am wondering what is the problem ?

**Below is my FirebaseInstance class implementation**

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d("No messages why ?", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("Horray", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }


        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }


private void showNotification(String title, String body) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "huxy.fcm.com.newfcmapp";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                   "Notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT );

            notificationChannel.setDescription("EDMT Channel");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

The full class can be viewed from the GitHub link here [Firebase Messaging instance class](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/NewFCMApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/huxy/fcm/com/newfcmapp/MyFirebaseInstanceService.java)

Then my `Manifest` file can also be accessed from here :
[Manifest file](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/NewFCMApp/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

You can also navigate my entire project to see if I have done any error, the project is just testing firebase cloud messaging. There's no other functionality.

Below is the link to the project :

[FCM sample project](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/NewFCMApp)

**This is the console I use to send messages:**

[image]

This is where I placed my **device token** :

[image]

Comment: Is the device token correct?
Please add another Service for the token generation. And register that in the manifest. 
<service android:name="YOUR_CLASS_NAME">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
It will extend FirebaseInstanceIdService

Comment: public class FirebaseIdGenerator extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private String TAG_CLASS = FirebaseIdGenerator.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Messages.logMessage(TAG_CLASS, "TOKEN *** - " + token);
       //sendTokenToServer();
    }
}

Comment: Use this for help and reference. 
https://github.com/udacity/AdvancedAndroid_Squawker/blob/TFCM.03-Solution-GetInstanceIdToken/app/src/main/java/android/example/com/squawker/fcm/SquawkFirebaseInstanceIdService.java

Comment: Hey, I got the reason as to why it wasn't working. My emulator's google play service wasn't up to date.